# Change color of a particular item in a listview as per the values from the database

Tags: android, date, listview, android-fragments

I have a fragment namely ScheduledFragment, in that fragment I have a custom listview. Am getting values from the server and inserting those values to list items.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scheduled, container, false);

    final ArrayList<CoursePojo> searchResults = GetSearchResults();


    final ListView lv1 = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvList2);

    lv1.setAdapter(new MyCustomCourseList(getActivity(), searchResults));
    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String currentid = ids.get(position);
            String currentcourse = cs.get(position);

            CoursePojo fullObject = (CoursePojo) o;              

        }
    });
    return rootView;}
```

Am adding of the value to an arraylist. MyCustomCourseList adapter class getView() is shown below

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view=convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
    holder.relativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rel1);
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(convertView.getResources().getColor(R.color.textColorPrimary));
```

Here am setting a color for my whole custom list. But what I really need is am getting some dates from the server, I need to change the background color the list item for some dates. I need to change the color of those list items, after comparing the dates which I get from the server and the current date. Those dates which are before the current date has to be shown in  background color "Color Primary" and those dates which are after current date has to be shown in color "color Secondary"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do some date comparison in getView and colour your layout based on that

```
if(validateDate(new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(c.getTime()),rowItem.getApiDate))
    holder.relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(convertView.getResources().getColor(R.color.textColorPrimary));
else
   holder.relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(convertView.getResources().getColor(R.color.textColorSecondary));
```

Comment: if it didn't helped you. do you need code Implementation.

Comment: Hi pramod thanks for the rply, but it didnt helped me as when i try to get the date it throws unparsebale exeception, it is because in getView () I dont have the have of the date. It would be grateful if you could give me some code implementation

Comment: Hi Pramod, I made a small mistake that I have given wrong format for date was causing the exception. Now its working like charm!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your above requirement by creating a communication between your fragment and adapter... I listed down following below.

- Set tag to relative layout
- In your fragment class implements an interface [this interface will play a role of bridge between fragment and adapter]
- In the interface's method you can access your adapter class and do whatever you want.

Comment: Hi Attiq, thnks for the rply. Could me give me some example code for the same

Comment: I could share my code but i think you have already resolve your issue by accepting Mishra's answer